# Correct Amplifier Rating for Klipsch RP-150M Speakers

Tags: speakers, amplifier, power

I am looking into buy a pair of bookshelf speakers, and have narrowed the field down to a pair of Klipsch RP-150Ms. However, before I purchase them, I would like to know if the amplifier/receiver I currently have will be enough to drive them in a small to medium sized room. The receiver I already own is 120 watts per channel, and is 8 ohms just like the speakers. Will this be enough to drive them well, or should I be looking into a more substantial amp to go with my speakers?

Comment: What is your usecase for the speakers?  What kind of SPL do you need to be able to produce?

Comment: The use would be personal use in a 14' by 14' room

Comment: Ok, that didn't really answer the question.  What are you listening to? Is it for analysis or listening?  What is the desired SPL (or SPL range) [ie, how loud]

Comment: 105 db Max, for listening to a wide range of music genres, but also possibly for (low level, I'm an amateur at creating and editing my own sounds) analysis of sound.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with Sound Design? Are you going to use these speakers to edit audio for feature film, documentary, television shows?

Comment: @Utopia, similar (but not applicable) questions to mine have been asked on this forum, which is why I felt like this was the appropriate place to ask such a question.

Comment: Ok. Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears those speakers are rated at 75 watt continuous, 300 watt peak power, so it sounds like they would do fine as long as your amp is decent.  It is worth pointing out that using a receiver as an amp is not an ideal situation for any analysis tasks as they are often designed to color the sound rather than simply amplify it depending on the type of receiver.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The receiver I have has been known to have a fairly flat response, so because I got it for free, I can tune it to a close enough standard to work for the light amounts of analysis I will be doing. Thanks again!